# Where are Java WebStart resources downloaded to?

Tags: java, java-web-start, jnlp

Can't locate stored files, but they seem to be downloaded only for the first time i run JNLP file. I'm on Mac OS X 10.6.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On my linux machine it is downloaded in the temporary folder '/tmp'.

if you need to uninstall (all) the cached application(s), call:

```
javaws -uninstall
```

or

```
javaws -uninstall <jnlp-file>
```

Answer (score 1):

It is configurable in the Java Preferences utility program.

For me it is in  /Users/me/Library/Caches/Java/cache